# How can I filter by message in all comments of a page post with graph api facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

This post have over 300000 comments and I want to filter which has my key.
I use this api to get all comment, then filter in local, but the maximum comments I receive is 5000.

```
graph.facebook.com/{post_id}/comments?fields=id&limit=1000000
```

How can I get all comments without limit (for post page have over million comments)?

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lower limit and use paging instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

You need to be careful with API limits though.

Comment: Thank you, but if I want to find a comment which contains my key word in 300.000 comments, how can I do it?

Comment: you have to go through all comments, there is no search option